# NoClassDefFound error while Running with PowerMock

Tags: powermock

I am getting this error:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/powermock/reflect/proxyframework/ClassLoaderRegisterProxyFramework
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractCommonTestSuiteChunkerImpl.registerProxyframework(AbstractCommonTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:101)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractCommonTestSuiteChunkerImpl.chunkClass(AbstractCommonTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:114)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractCommonTestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(AbstractCommonTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:60)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractCommonTestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(AbstractCommonTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:54)
    at org.powermock.tests.utils.impl.AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(AbstractTestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:58)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.<init>(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.<init>(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:32)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.<init>(PowerMockRunner.java:34)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.buildRunner(AnnotatedBuilder.java:104)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AnnotatedBuilder.runnerForClass(AnnotatedBuilder.java:86)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.builders.AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.runnerForClass(AllDefaultPossibilitiesBuilder.java:26)
    at org.junit.runners.model.RunnerBuilder.safeRunnerForClass(RunnerBuilder.java:59)
    at org.junit.internal.requests.ClassRequest.getRunner(ClassRequest.java:33)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createUnfilteredTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:84)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.createTest(JUnit4TestLoader.java:70)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestLoader.loadTests(JUnit4TestLoader.java:43)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:444)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.powermock.reflect.proxyframework.ClassLoaderRegisterProxyFramework
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    ... 25 more
```

I've added these dependencies in my pom.xml. I've already checked the stackflow for similar implementations and did a clean install. My project is building file but running tests is giving error. I am trying to run through eclipse.

```
    <!-- Power Mock dependencies -->
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
                <artifactId>mockito-all</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
                <artifactId>powermock-api-mockito</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
                <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4</artifactId>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
                <artifactId>powermock-module-junit4-legacy</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
                <artifactId>powermock-reflect</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.0</version>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
                <artifactId>powermock-api-easymock</artifactId>
                <version>1.7.0</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.easymock</groupId>
                <artifactId>easymock</artifactId>
                <version>3.4</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>
```

I am running java class with PowerMockRunner and injecting my test class using annotation InjectMock. Then mocking static class using MockStatic method. Also, i've  added PrepareForTest annotation and added Class which has static methods in that location.

I updated my code and followed few examples, but this error is coming. What am i am doing wrong?

```
My code is like this. 
 class A{ 
void static method testA(String str){ .... do something; }
}

 class B{ 
     testB(String s) 
                 { A.testA(s); 
     }
 }
```

Now when i try to run test case on my class A using PowerMockRunner. I've given annotations on testcase @preparefortest({A.class}) @runwith(PowerMockRunner.class)

Comment: My code is like this.  I've a similar code
class A{

void static method testA(String str){
.... do something;
}
class B{
testB(String s)
{
A.testA(s);
}
}
Now when i try to run test case on my class A
using PowerMockRunner.
I've given annotations on testcase
@preparefortest({A.class})
@runwith(PowerMockRunner.class)

Comment: Made changes, thanks.

Comment: Never put more information into comments. Or can you read that first comment? I can't and I don't want to. Please **edit** your question and add all missing parts!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I saw the same error when using PowerMock 1.7.1. In the absence of an explicit dependency, maven was pulling in version 1.6.5 of powermock-core. Adding an explicit dependency on version 1.7.1 of powermock-core fixed this error for me.

So your solution should be to add an explicit dependency on version 1.7.0 of powermock-core:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.powermock</groupId>
    <artifactId>powermock-core</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.0</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```